# QML: scope of id's

Tags: qt, scope, qml

Say I've created an object with an id `foo`. How far is the object visible by the name `foo`? Everywhere in the current file? Everywhere in the current directory? Or what?

I read the QML documentation on [scope](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html) but I didn't find info on this there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311602/991484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the [id attribute documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute).

It says:

> An object can be referred to by its `id` from anywhere within the *component scope* in which it is declared.

And "component scope" is defined in [the scope documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using `id`s to reference objects in a single source is all fine and dandy, but there is more to the story. `id`s will also resolve down the object tree:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 600
  height: 300

  property int test: 667

  Obj { }
}

// Obj.qml
Item {
  Obj2 {}
}

// Obj2.qml
QtObject {
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(main.test)
}
```

As this example illustrates, the `main` `id` resolves from `Obj2` that is created in `Obj` that is created in `main.qml`. In this aspect the id works very much like dynamic scope properties, with one notable exception, dynamic scope properties will only work if they are declared in the root object of a particular source, whereas the `id` will resolve regardless of which object it is declared in, as long as it is in that source and of course, as long as it is not shadowed. I guess internally they do end up sort of transferred to the root object, as they become attributes for that component. Common logic dictates lookup performance would be similar to that of dynamic properties. To further reinforce the similarity with dynamic scope properties, both are not possible to chain and only resolve from the particular qml file. You cannot `someObject.someDynamicScopeProperty` just like you cannot `someObject.someId`, even if both the property and the `id` are resolvable from within `SomeObject`.

This is actually a lot more useful than it may appear initially. It will allow to reference objects down a known tree branch without the need to go back and meticulously interface properties or aliases in order to expose the branch structure for lookups. This is also a very good reason to use meaningful and unique identifiers for `id`s, rather than using `id: root` for the root object of every qml file.