# What is the scope of ID in QML?

Tags: qt, scope, qml, qt5

The document said we cannot have the **same ID** in one file. That means we can have the same id in different file,right? I don't know the scope of ID in QML,so i write the code as following to test it.

```
//a.qml
Item {
  id: a_item
  x:20;
  y:b_item.x // cannot access this id
  y:b1.x1 // can access
  Item {
    id:a1 
    x:20
    Component.onCompleted : a1.x //this a1 is a.qml's a1 not the a1 in main.qml
  }
}

//b.qml
Item {
  id: b_item
  x:20;
  property int x1: 30;
}

//main.qml
Item {
  a {
    id:a1
    Component.onCompleted : b1.x = 1 //can access
  }
  b {
   id:b1
  }
  function() {
    a_item.x = 1; // cannot access this id
  }
}
```

**My question**:

1.

What is the scope of ID in QML? In my test, the result shows that Item cannot access the id of its childen and his brother 's chilren, but can access his **parent or brother**, right?

2.

the **same id** in **different file** just i show in my code, no error and i worked. But how can i **differentiate** them.

Comment: why c++?.......

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The canonical answer would be:

> The scope of `id`s is the component scope.

And the component scope is:

> Each QML component in a QML document defines a logical scope. Each
>   document has at least one root component, but can also have other
>   inline sub-components. The component scope is the union of the object
>   ids within the component and the component's root object's properties.

Which itself is not overly informative on what the scope exactly is and how can you make optimal use of it. A tad more informative:

> In QML, component instances connect their component scopes together to
>   form a scope hierarchy. Component instances can directly access the
>   component scopes of their ancestors.

Basically, each `id` in a qml file is implemented sort of like a property of that source's root item. Except it cannot be accessed via `someobj.someId`, only via `someId`.

Which means that this id can be accessed by any object that exists in the branch that extends from the root object thanks to qml's dynamic scoping.

That is as long as it is not shadowed by an identically named `id` or `property`.

`a_item` will be visible in `a.qml` as well as any object that exists in the branch its root `Item` grows.

It won't be visible from `main.qml` as that object is further down the tree, where `a_item` is not defined.

In the same line of thought, `b1` can be accessed from `a.qml` because `b1` is defined in `main.qml` which is where `a.qml` is instantiated. But `b_item` will 
not be visible from there.

In fact, since `a1` and `b1` are defined in `main.qml` which is the root of the entire application tree, those two `id`s will be visible from every object of the application, as long as it is a part of the object tree and as long as the identifiers are not shadowed. Note that they will not be visible from singletons or parent-less objects, as those are not part of the application object tree.

```
obj tree                a1  b1  a_item  b_item
main.qml                D   D   X       X
        a.qm            V   V   D       X
            Item a1     V   V   V       X
        b.qml           V   V   X       D

D - defined here, V - visible here, X - not available
```

The same is true for properties, although dynamic scoping only works for properties that are defined for the qml file root element, unlike `id`s which are visible even if they are on a different sub-branch, which is why in the first sentence of this answer I put it as "implemented sort of a property of that source's root item":

```
Obj
  Obj
    Obj
      id: objid
      property objprop
  CustomObj
```

So `objid` will be visible in `CustomObj`, but `objprop` will not be, since it is not an id and not defined in the root object. The `id` is identical to doing this:

```
Obj
  property objid : _objid
  Obj
    Obj
      id: _objid
```

All `id`s from a given sources are visible in the qml source root object's context and subsequently everything else that will eventually drop down to this context as it lookup fails to resolve the identifier in the "higher" contexts.

Finally, keep in mind the subtle trap - it is only possible to use `id`s across sources if you know for certain that your application will instantiate the objects in a compatible context tree.

For example:

```
A.qml {
  id: objA
  B { } // objA will be visible to this object
}

main.qml
  A {
    B {} // objA will NOT be visible to this object
  }
  B {} // objA will NOT be visible to this object
```

The trap continues - **context tree comes before object tree** - the context in which an object is created matters, and **cannot be changed once set** (puts certain limits on reparenting depending on context dependencies).

```
// ObjA.qml
Item {
  id: objA
  Component {
    id: cm
    ObjB {}
  }
  function create() { cm.createObject(objA) }
}

// ObjB.qml
Item {
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(objA)
}

// main.qml
  Component {
    id: cm
    Rect {}
  }

  Obj {
    anchors.fill: parent
    MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
      onClicked: {
        if (mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton) {
          cm.createObject(parent)
        } else {
          parent.create()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As this practical example illustrates, even though in both cases the newly created object is parented to the same object that has the `objA` identifier, the object created in `main.qml` cannot resolve it, because it is created in a context where `objA` is still not defined, but it works if the object is created in the context of `objA`, and it will work even if it is burred even higher up the tree.

To put it in a more generic way, an `id` becomes visible in the context of the source's root object and remains visible in every subsequent sub-context until it is shadowed by an identically named object. Visibility cannot reach down the tree to contexts that exist before the context the `id` is defined in. 
Note the subtle difference - `a_item` refers to an `Item` whereas `a1` refers to an `a`. And since `a1` is visible inside `a.qml` it will always refer to that one instance of `a` that is in `main.qml`, regardless of which instance of `a` you might be in, whereas `a_item` will refer to a different object for each different instance of `a`. `a_item` is "relative" and will be different in every different instance of `a` but `a1` is absolute and will always refer to a specific instance of `a`. This is the case because `a1` is a concrete instance whereas `a_item` is a type / prototype.

```
// Obj.qml
Item {
  id: obj
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(obj === oid)
}

// main.qml    
  Obj { } // false
  Obj { id: oid } // true
```

Dynamic scoping of `id`s can be quite useful and cut the time it takes to implement a workaround to get access to the stuff you need. Which is also why it is a very good idea to give the `id` descriptive names rather than just `main`.

For example, if you have a `manager` that manages a number of `views`, each with a number of `objects` in them, you can quickly get access the respective `view` for each `object` and also get access to the manager without having to implement any additional stuff. The rule of thumb is that the `manager` must come first, then each `view` should be created in the context of the `manager`, not necessarily directly in it, but in it nonetheless, and each `object` should be created in the context of a `view`. And of course take care not to shadow over things. If you break that rule things will not resolve properly.

```
View.qml { id: view }

manager
  view1
    object // view is view1
  view2
    object // view is view2
  view3
    object // view is view3
```

Naturally, this makes sense only in specific purpose designs where you know what the general structure of the context tree is gonna be like. If you are making generic elements that may go just about anywhere, you should **absolutely not** be relying on accessing `id`s across sources, and you should implement a more generic usage interface via properties, aliases and whatnot.